# Viewing Content of checkbox underneath the checkbox both visible?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I have a grid of many checkboxes, they are 70 height and 47 width. For a single checkbox, I want the checkbox's check mark box to stay visible and fully opaque on top of whatever is within the checkbox itself. In this case the only content of the checkbox will be an image (it is the same size 70height 47width) that is moved so that it lines up with the whole box. However the image's opacity covers the check mark box.

As of right now I have this (it isn't what I want so much as shows the problem). The opacity of the image is there so you can see the image and checkbox. The margin puts the image over the whole checkbox

```
<CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Opacity="1" BorderThickness="0" Unchecked="CheckBoxChange" Checked="CheckBoxChange" TabIndex="7" IsTabStop="True">
    <Image Source="Resources/1.png" Width="47" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="-18,1,0,0" Opacity=".4"/>
</CheckBox>
```

If you do a similar format of this for a button it works fine but I need try this with checkbox because it far better fits the use of the function needed.

Is there a way to do what I've explained or do I need to make something custom?